# how to add html tag in django dictonary

Tags: html, django

I have added a strong tag in Django dict but not working

```
mylist = [{'hq': 'abc', 'inst': 'Total', 'trade': 'Fitter'}]
```

I added like this but it rendered the same not highlights

```
mylist = [{'hq': 'abc', 'inst': '<strong>Total</strong>', 'trade': 'Fitter'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django autoescape all strings when render its in templates for security reasons.

You can disable it when render with the `safe` template filter or `autoescape` template tag:

```erlang
{{ myvar|safe }}

{% autoescape off %}
    {{ myvar }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Or mark previously the variable as a safe string.

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

mylist = [{
    'hq': 'abc', 
    'inst': mark_safe('<strong>Total</strong>'), 
    'trade': 'Fitter'
}]
```